# JavaScript - touchstart not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

Just a simple JavaScript to resize a div when an `<a>` is clicked. Doesn't seem to work on my iPhone.

Starts with a simple link:

```
<a href="#" onfocus="menu()">MENU</a>
```

which expands a div to full screen and displays content. Inside that div,

```
<a href="#" onfocus="revert()">close</a>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>
        var headerHeight = document.getElementById("header_container").clientHeight;
        function menu() {
            document.getElementById("nav_container").style = "display:block;";
            document.getElementById("header_container").style = "height:100%";
            document.getElementById("header").style = "height:100%";
        }
        function revert(){
            document.getElementById("nav_container").style = "display:none;";
            document.getElementById("header_container").style = "height:"+headerHeight+";";
            document.getElementById("header").style = "height:"+headerHeight+";";
        }
</script>
```

Works perfectly on the desktop, using Firefox Dev Ed. in responsive design mode, with `Simulate touch events` enabled. Doesn't seem to work on my mobile device :-(

I hit the button and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: a) better semantics would be to use a `<button>` element; b) try `onclick` instead of `onfocus`.

Answer (score 0):

An element is 'focused' when it is ready to accept keyboard input, I think you probably want `onclick` instead.

Also, you probably want a button if you're not linking to another page. So your HTML would look like this:

```
<button onclick="menu()">MENU</button>
<button onclick="revert()">close</button>
```

That will work, but we can do better. If you do this, you need to have `menu` and `revert` functions defined *before* your buttons. This means you need to load your JavaScript before the DOM, which means your JavaScript can't reference the DOM.

Better to put your JavaScript *after* all your DOM is loaded and bind your events there, like so:

```js
function menu() {
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = 'Showing menu';
}

function revert(){
  document.getElementById("msg").textContent = 'Not showing menu';
}

// bind all events
document.getElementById('open-menu-button').addEventListener('click', menu);
document.getElementById('close-menu-button').addEventListener('click', revert);
```

```html
<button id="open-menu-button">MENU</button>
<button id="close-menu-button">close</button>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

You will see lots of bad info out there telling you that you need to wait for some domloaded event before doing this, or wrap everything in `$( document ).ready()`. That is all untrue, as long as your JavaScript comes at the bottom of the page.